# Creating mobile app in Symfony2

Tags: php, android, symfony, mobile, cordova

I read that there is an option to create a mobile app in symfony2 and I don't really understand how to create it. As much as I do understand the concepct of emulating HTML5 to native app I don't know HOW to do the same thing with symfony.

Lets say that we created the app in html5. We just go through the process with PhoneGap and it creates the native app ( yeah, I know, very simplified ). But how should I do it with Symfony? I mean.. is there any similar emulator for php and...all the files that symfony contains or.. or what? How to make it work on iOS, how on Android, how on Windows Phone and BlackBerry..

Sorry for dumb question but I couldn't find proper answer.

Comment: Since Symfony2 is a PHP framework, I seriously doubt it could in any way generate a compiled Java application. Maybe the author meant you can use Symfony2 apps as Backend for your app or even include it's generated HTML in you PhoneGap ? Link?

Comment: for example here: http://www.slideshare.net/pgodel/creating-mobile-apps-with-php-symfony2

Comment: This link shows that you can create a normal HTML website on a server that produces HTML code optomized for mobile web browsers (by using JQuery mobile). It is NOT creating a native mobile app. Not even a hybrid like PhoneGap does. The title is misleading. ;)

Comment: holly cow xD and what about this link: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-web-app-symfony-2-development/

Comment: Second link only show how to use Symfony2 to do what it is designed to do: Create web pages, not native mobile apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No questions are dumb when it's asked in real sense :)

Web App is different from Mobile App.

Symfony is a PHP framework and its no where realted to Phonegap/Cordova. PhoneGap/Cordova uses HTML, CSS and some javascript. You can use some PHP for some backend services but not for the app itself.

So my final point would be you can not use Symfony to create a phonegap app.

Comment: and what about not phonegap app? just a mobile app written in symfony compiled to work on android/iOS ?

Comment: You can only create a web app(may be responsive for mobile) using symfony and not an native app which works on android/iOs.

Comment: Not completely correct: You can point the content URL of your PhoneGap app to an external web source, ie a Symphony2 generated mobile website. That said, Symfony2 per se still is only a framework to generate web services or websites, not mobile apps alone without some hybrid framework like PhoneGap.

Comment: agreed.. it has to be a web viwew wrapped in app. but the content shoould be in a server and not in device.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, symfony provides a solid framework for HTTP and restful API through which jQuery mobile can be configured and then if you extend TWIG for a template, then Symfony acts as the bundler and composer through with routing can take place. While Symfony does not run native apps, they need to retrieve and store data and on that front a framework such as Symfony works well.  So one could argue that one could use APIs for multiple clients (iOS, Android and more) and then reuse controllers and use formats to generate XML/JSON thus theoretically it should work with Phonegap too.