# Web to Native app - Request & Response - Listening service

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services

This is a very general question, however I have done some research and believe I am simply missing some useful terminology of the concepts in question, and if someone could point me in the right direction it would be helpful.

Basically I am creating a PHP page, that will send a request - this will then be received by a native app.  Where the user will either accept or decline the request.  This will then be sent back to the PHP page.

So my queries..

- What technologies or key concepts need to be applied here..
  Main areas
  -- PHP to send request
  -- Native app to be listening for requests
  -- PHP to be able to listen for the response
  -- All needs to happen in real time i.e. user requests service, administrator confirms/declines, user receives response.  All within in est. 60 seconds.

Comment: You can fire notification from php to device, then from device send message to service that, notification received. Do you want this?

Comment: I want php to device....then once user on device confirms/declines, that to be received back to the listening PHP...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go into the right direction and you want all this to be on PHP, I would look at PHP RESTful service. Maybe 
read up on this resource: [http://www.amazon.com/RESTful-PHP-Services-Technologies-Solutions-ebook/dp/B005VQ8SB6/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1419012976&sr=1-1&keywords=9781847195531](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005VQ8SB6)

You can also look into Symphony or Zend frameworks, there are other frameworks that has  similar feature. If you need this quick, you can get it installed and test out what you're looking to accomplish.

Also take a look at Symphony snippet on Request & Response - Listening service
    http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-how-to-create-a-custom-response-using-an-event-listener/

### Something on previous post from Stackoverflow

symfony provides a solid framework for HTTP and restful API through which jQuery mobile can be configured and then if you extend TWIG for a template, then Symfony acts as the bundler and composer through with routing can take place. While Symfony does not run native apps, they need to retrieve and store data and on that front a framework such as Symfony works well. So one could argue that one could use APIs for multiple clients (iOS, Android and more) and then reuse controllers and use formats to generate XML/JSON thus theoretically it should work with Phonegap too.

@ref: [Creating mobile app in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357993/creating-mobile-app-in-symfony2)